# Uncheck "Checkboxes" in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code to uncheck all the Checkboxes in sheet.

It doesn't change the boxes. I get the message box confirming that the range is green and therefore the loop should kick in.

```
Sub Changeboxes()

'Dim cb As CheckBox'

If Sheet1.Range("a1").Value = "green" Then

    MsgBox "The range is green.", vbOKOnly

    For Each cb In Sheet1.CheckBoxes
        cb.Value = True
    Next cb

Else
    MsgBox "The range is NOT green.", vbOKOnly

End If

MsgBox "Checked availability updated.", vbOKOnly

End Sub
```

Comment: Are the checkboxes from the "form controls" or the "activex controls" section of the insert dropdown?

Comment: It will work for form controls.  Also `Sheet1` is the codename for the sheet - the name _not_ in brackets in the VBE.  These can go out of sync with the name you see on the sheet tab - definitely looking at the right sheet?  Saying that should be as it's reading "green" out of A1.

Comment: Hi @Nick, these are the activex controls. Would there be a different code? The code doesn't work with = false either!

Comment: Hi @Darren Bartrup-Cook. Yes, the sheet name is in sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line : `cb.Value = True`  to `cb.Value = False` to uncheck the boxes.

**EDIT**

Yes, if the checkboxes are activex objects then the above code will not work. Instead, use the following code:

```
Sub ChangeBoxes()
Dim obj As OLEObject

If Sheet1.Range("a1").Value = "green" Then

    MsgBox "The range is green.", vbOKOnly

        For Each obj In Sheet1.OLEObjects

            obj.Object.Value = True
        Next

    MsgBox "Checked availability updated.", vbOKOnly

Else

    MsgBox "The range is NOT green.", vbOKOnly

End If

End Sub
```

I have also moved the last messagebox into the first part of the if statement because it was popping up whether or not the value in A1 was green.